# porqué no me acepta la sintaxis normal?

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript

esto tratando de definir variables pero no me los inicializa y eso que ya las estoy usando, ¿como soluciono este problema? solo me soluciona el problema añadiendole "!" como si fuera una negación, no se si esa es la solución adjunto evidencia[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al añadir el símbolo ! le estas diciendo a typeScript que esta variable tendrá un valor o es underfined `email!: string` como no le diste ningún valor a esta variable typeScript detecta el error ante de la ejecución y no te deja al menos que se lo indiques `email!: string o email: string | underfined`

Answer (score 1):

Siempre inicializar las variables =>  email:String = ""; <= string vacío, o podés => email:String = "email@Mail.com";

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esta sintaxis

```
email!:string
```

Luego puedes asignar el valor en el ciclo de vida del componente que necesites